# ImageLoader- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, exception, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I developing an android app that requires me to display some images by getting it from the server at the run_time, so I get it's **thumbnail** and then use [Android-Universal-ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/) to get these images:

```
   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
   ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

      // to get the movie_poster from the server
        private void setImageResource_season(ImageButton image, String url){

            loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            loader.displayImage(url, image);

        }
```

when it's a little amount of images everything goes well, but when it's like about **100** images the `ImageLoader` gives me like from **10** to **15** images then it passes me that exception:

```
    02-19 15:14:30.018: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(597): Out of memory on a 1382416-byte allocation.
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597): "uil-pool-1-thread-1" prio=4 tid=16 RUNNABLE
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x413f6e18 self=0x1e05c8
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   | sysTid=649 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2031848
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   | schedstat=( 17149851689 41024927609 1804 ) utm=1582 stm=132 core=0
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:78)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:289)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:245)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:141)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-19 15:14:30.018: INFO/dalvikvm(597):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-19 15:14:30.108: DEBUG/skia(597): --- decoder->decode returned false

    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597): null
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:78)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:289)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:245)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:141)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    02-19 15:15:10.008: ERROR/ImageLoader(597):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: have you tried to turn on largeHeap?

Comment: try to use this method by passing options **imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, displayOptions);**

Comment: @nikis now i tried, still the same

Comment: In such a case maybe your images are too large? Anyway, you should optimize your loading method

Comment: How big are the images? Have you tried scaling? How many do you show on the screen at the same time?

Comment: @Magnus the size of the images is pretty big and may or may not differ from one image to another, and i didn't try to scale any of them, and i'm displaying a pop-up window which will show like about 9 images and the pop_up will be scrollable to display like 200 images.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

within the `application tag` into your manifest

Example

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
```